# "I ______ the bus home every day this month."

Tags: tense

I got this MCQ in Fiverr English Test. I don't know whether option 1 or 3 is correct. I prefer 1, but I am not confident of my answer being correct. Hence, I have shared it with you so that I can be assured.

> I ______ the bus home every day this month.
>
> 1. am taking
> 2. was taking
> 3. take
> 4. had taken

Comment: Hi Community, you've got the wrong comment here.  There is a single question, this issue is, as Ronald says, a lack of prior research.   @Apu I can guess why this is confusing, but can you give some explanation of why you have a doubt.

Answer (score 4):

The test setter almost certaintly wants "am taking"  The present continuous tense can be used for repeated actions that are temporary.  In this case it seems that you didn't take the bus last month, and you might not take the bus next month. So there is a temporary period in which you are taking the bus.

For this reason, "take" is not correct. The simple present tense is used for facts that are always or generally true.

The other answers use a past tense, and the time "this month" is present.

<sub>In fact the past tense answers are also possible:  "I was taking the bus home this month, but on Friday the bus company stopped the route, so on Monday I had to walk." Or "I had taken the bus home this month, so I had a bus ticket in my pocket yesterday."  These are unlikely, and I doubt the person setting the test thought of this kind of context</sub>